# Pytube giving an error for downloading video in 480p resolutio

Tags: python, download, pytube

Actually I am trying to download videos with pytube in 480p but getting an error like

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'download'**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to uninstall *pytube* and install *pytube3*

`pip install pytube3`